# ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile 'open' failed iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uiimage, cgimage

I have images set into xib for an iPad app,On application launch the images disappear for iOS 7.It works fine for iOS 8 device but fails for iOS iPad for random attempts.

Below is the log printed by the app:

: ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/var/mobile/Applications/7B81CFF6-44D4-4181-8051-7C6E38A9BA39/Photo Party.app/button_green_nul@2x.png'
             error = 24 (Too many open files)

ImageIO: CGImageReadCreateDataWithMappedFile  'open' failed '/var/mobile/Applications/7B81CFF6-44D4-4181-8051-7C6E38A9BA39/Photo Party.app/default_bg.jpg'

: ImageIO: JPEG Not a JPEG file: starts with 0xff 0xd9